# Parameterize object with enum

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using C# and Unity Dependency Injection for developing a MVVM application in WPF. I'm looking for a cleanest solution for a following problem.

Some of my classes are parametrized with enums, for example, I have a class AudioChannelViewModel (let's call it for short A) and I want to register two instances of the class, one for Channel.Left and one for Channel.Right. This alone is not a problem, because I register those instances by naming them in RegisterType and then referring to them later by `[Dependency(name)]` attribute.

Moreover, A depends on some other classes, lets call them Dep1, Dep2 and Dep3. To perform the initialization of A, I must have ALL of my dependencies and the information about the Channel.

I tried to use the following strategies:

1. Property injection of Dep1, Dep2 and Dep3 and setting A's Channel in constructor by RegisterType with InjectionConstructor parameter. But how should I know when A is ready to be initialized? AFAIK I cannot assume anything about the property injection order.
2. Constructor injection of all four items. It would be IMHO the cleanest solution, as I would be able to perform initialization in constructor. But I'm unable to get this working in Unity. Registering A with InjectionConstructor param for Channel throws an exception, and registering with four InjectionConstructor params seems ugly.
3. Constructor injection of Dep1, Dep2 and Dep3 and property injection of Channel. Then I can initialize my class in the Channel setter. It works for this case, but what if A would be parametrized by more than one property? Then I wouldn't know when A is fully built up and ready for initialization.

How should the initialization be performed? Or maybe I'm making things overly complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say exactly what the exception was that you observed in strategy #2, but this is the approach I would be using (given your other requirements for being able to other initialisation having had all the dependencies successfully resolved). I suspect the problem is that you aren't providing a 'value' for all of the arguments of the constructor... `InjectionConstructor` assumes the constructor you want is the one matching the types of the values provided to the `InjectionConstructor`.

E.g. if you want to register a constructor for such a class...

```
public class AudioChannelViewModel {
  public AudioChannelViewModel(Channel channel, Dep1 dep1, Dep2 dep2, Dep3 dep3) {
    ...
  }
}
```

You should register it thus...

```
container.RegisterType<AudioChannelViewModel>("left", 
    new InjectionConstructor(Channel.Left,
      typeof(Dep1), typeof(Dep2), typeof(Dep3)));
container.RegisterType<AudioChannelViewModel>("right", 
    new InjectionConstructor(Channel.Right,
      typeof(Dep1), typeof(Dep2), typeof(Dep3)));
```

Unity will use the provided value for the first argument (a `Channel` enum value) and will then resolve the `Dep1`, `Dep2` and `Dep3` instances. You can also use `ResolvedParameter<T>` as an argument to `InjectionConstructor` if there were specific named instances of `Dep1`, `Dep2` or `Dep3` that you require.

Just providing `Channel.Left` or `Channel.Right` alone is insufficient, as Unity will believe it is being asked to use a constructor with just a `Channel` argument.

Or; if you HAVE already tried that and it isn't working... maybe Unity doesn't support enums in this instance (pun intended).

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx) might shine some more light on the issue.

Comment: Oh, I simply did not know that I can pass the type of the dependency to the InjectionConstructor's constructor. Thanks! Your approach works perfectly.